# spark join with column multiple values in list

Tags: sql, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

I have

Dataset A: uuid, listOfLocationsIds, name

Dataset B: locationId, latitude, longitude

A.listOfLocationIds can have multiple locationIds

How can I do a join on A and B with each value in listOfLocationsIds?
So if there are two values in listOfLocationIds, I would want the join to consider each locationId in the listOfLocationIds

```
A.join(B, A.listOfLocationsIds[0] == B.locationId, "left")
A.join(B, A.listOfLocationsIds[1] == B.locationId, "left")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume dataset A is called `df` with this content:

```
+----+-----------------+-----+
|uuid|listOfLocationsId|name |
+----+-----------------+-----+
|1   |[1, 2, 3]        |name1|
|2   |[1, 3]           |name1|
+----+-----------------+-----+
```

and dataset B is called `df2` with this content:

```
+----------+--------+---------+
|locationId|latitude|longitude|
+----------+--------+---------+
|2         |5       |7        |
+----------+--------+---------+
```

And we do an `array_contains` join:

```
df = df.join(df2, 
  array_contains(col("listOfLocationsId"), col("locationId")), "left"
)
```

The final result:

```
+----+-----------------+-----+----------+--------+---------+
|uuid|listOfLocationsId|name |locationId|latitude|longitude|
+----+-----------------+-----+----------+--------+---------+
|1   |[1, 2, 3]        |name1|2         |5       |7        |
|2   |[1, 3]           |name1|null      |null    |null     |
+----+-----------------+-----+----------+--------+---------+
```

Good luck!

Comment: what if the list can have unknown number of elements?

Comment: edited the comment, guess this is what you are looking for